# Backtracking Maze Algorithm Starts off Wrong in C

Tags: c, maze

Been working on this project for past week.
Everything but initialization/mallocing and step function was provided beforehand to me by my professor...

The goal isn't to create the maze but just solve it.
My first time getting it compiled it seemed to run fine and would go somewhat through it... Then, it would start to do some funky stuff and skip through a wall then stop there...

Tried fixing it and going through it. Ended up with it not having first step where it should now. Trying to understand what I am doing wrong or why am I not doing correct first step now
in my maze_client...//provided but I can change a bit if needed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "maze.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   Maze maze = initializeMaze(fp);
   findPath(maze);// first step.. It was provided to me. It basically calls step() 
   displayMaze(maze);
   return 0;
}
```

Step function... I made another that isn't for loop and I tried to see if I could get rid of the crap too. Didn't work just made it start first step somewhere else random... The second file complete over try I blocked out each function... It seemed to be in my `if(getBottom)` statement...I can write down my logic steps of what I want it to do if needed...

```
static int step(Maze maze, int row, int column)
{
  //TODO: FINISH THE BACKTRACKING ALGORITHM
  int i,j;
  //int st;
  int successful;
 //maze->maze[row][column] = st;

 if(getVisit(maze, row, column) == maze->maze[maze->finishX][maze->finishY])
 {
   displayMaze(maze);
   return 1;
 }

 displayMaze(maze);
 getchar();
 // getVisit(maze, row, column);//gets pos
 for(i = -2; i <= 2; ++i)
 {
   for(j = -2; j <= 2; ++j)
   {
    //i*i != j*j dont move in diagonal
     //row+i >= 0 && row + i < n, bounds checking
     //col+j >= 0 && col+j < n, bounds checking
    if(i*i != j*j && row+i >= 0 && column+j >= 0 ) 
    {
      getVisit(maze, row, column);//Gets position 
        if(getCellHasTop(maze, row, column + 1) != 1)//Wall check, Zero meaning NO WALL
        {
                 //++st;
                 //gets that position and sees if it is unvisited... 
                 //need a test if it is visited.. if it has been visited before.. Set current spot as BAD_PATH
                 if(getVisit(maze,row,column+j) == UNVISITED)
                 {
                    setVisit(maze, row, column+1, GOOD_PATH);
                  successful = step(maze, row, column + 1);
                 }
              // if(getVisit(maze, row, column+j) == GOOD_PATH)
              //   {
              //   setVisit(maze, row-i, column, BAD_PATH);
          //   successful = step(maze, row, column+j);
            //      }
                 if(successful)
                   return 1;  
        }
        if(getCellHasLeft(maze,row - 1,column) != 1)
        {
                 if(getVisit(maze, row-1, column) == UNVISITED)
                 {
                 setVisit(maze, row-1, column, GOOD_PATH);
                 successful = step(maze, row-1, column);
                 }

              //   if(getVisit(maze, row-i, column) == GOOD_PATH)
               //  {
              //setVisit(maze, row-i, column, BAD_PATH);
              // successful = step(maze, row-i, column);
               //  }
                 //++st;
                 if(successful)
                return 1;
        }
        if(getCellHasRight(maze,row + 1, column) != 1)
        {
                 if(getVisit(maze, row+1, column) == UNVISITED)
                 {
                  setVisit(maze, row+1, column, GOOD_PATH);
                  successful = step(maze, row+1, column);
                 }

               //  if(getVisit(maze, row+i, column) == GOOD_PATH)
  //               {
    //            setVisit(maze, row+i, column, BAD_PATH);
      //            successful = step(maze, row+i, column);
        //        }
                 //++st;
                 if(successful)
                return 1;
        }
        if(getCellHasBottom(maze, row, column - 1) != 1)
        {
                 if(getVisit(maze, row, column-1) == UNVISITED)
                 {
                  setVisit(maze, row, column-1, GOOD_PATH);
                  successful = step(maze, row, column-1);
                 }

      //           if(getVisit(maze, row, column-j) == GOOD_PATH)
        //       {
          //        setVisit(maze, row, column-j, BAD_PATH);
            //    successful = step(maze, row, column-j);
              //   }
                 //++st;
                 if(successful)
                return 1;  
        }  
        //PART 2
        //Do not do else if because then each one would require... That is last resort
    if(getCellHasTop(maze, row, column + 1) == 0)//Wall check
        {
                 //++st;
                 //a test if it is visited.. if it has been visited before.. Set current spot as BAD_PATH   
                 if(getVisit(maze,row, column+1) == GOOD_PATH)
               {
                  setVisit(maze, row, column, BAD_PATH);
                  successful = step(maze, row, column + 1);
                }
                if(successful)
              return 1;  
        }
       if(getCellHasLeft(maze,row - 1,column) == 0)
        {
                 if(getVisit(maze, row-1, column) == GOOD_PATH)
                 {
               setVisit(maze, row, column, BAD_PATH);
                successful = step(maze, row-1, column);
                }
   //++st;
               if(successful)
            return 1;
 }
if(getCellHasRight(maze,row + 1, column) == 0)
        {
                if(getVisit(maze, row+1, column) == GOOD_PATH)
                {
                 setVisit(maze, row, column, BAD_PATH);
                 successful = step(maze, row+1, column);
                }
                 //++st;
      if(successful)
     return 1;
       }
       if(getCellHasBottom(maze, row, column - 1) == 0)
   {
                if(getVisit(maze, row, column-1) == GOOD_PATH)
 {
                  setVisit(maze, row, column, BAD_PATH);
                  successful = step(maze, row, column-1);
                }
                 //++st;
                 if(successful)
              return 1;  
       }  
        //Part 3
       if(getCellHasRight(maze, row + 1, column) != 0 && getCellHasLeft(maze,row - 1, column) != 0)// If there is a wall at those locationsZZ
        {
                if(getVisit(maze,row, column+1) == BAD_PATH)
                 {
                 setVisit(maze, row, column, BAD_PATH);
      successful = step(maze, row, column-1); 
                 }
                 if(successful)
                return 1;
 }
       if(getCellHasTop(maze, row, column + 1) != 0 && getCellHasBottom(maze, row, column - 1) != 0)
   {
                 if(getVisit(maze, row-1, column) == BAD_PATH)
                 {
                 setVisit(maze, row, column, BAD_PATH);
                  successful = step(maze, row+1, column);
                }
               if(successful)
              return 1;
     }
        if(getCellHasTop(maze, row, column +1) != 0 && getCellHasBottom(maze, row, column - 1) != 0)
      {
              if(getVisit(maze, row+1, column) == BAD_PATH)
           {
         setVisit(maze, row, column, BAD_PATH);
             successful = step(maze, row-1, column);
              }
         if(successful)
      return 1;
       }
      }  
     } 
     }
      displayMaze(maze);
      getchar();
    return 0;
    }
```

- Full code of the functions: http://pastebin.com/PtAncpqS
- Header file (provided): http://pastebin.com/zYdCFMfX
- Scanner(provided): http://pastebin.com/4nQdnXTP
- Scanner header: http://pastebin.com/KjpFf83R
- Second try: http://pastebin.com/8qyuqtEv

Comment: Looking at your code, you have several problems. The most obvious is looping from -2 to +2 row and column. Why would you do any looping, if you have predicates that indicate whether a cell has a top,left, right, etc? If you can get that information from the cell, you don't need to do any offset computations at all - they've been done for you.

Comment: Also, I hate your function names. Seriously, `getCellHasTop`? I'm getting the impression that someone in your school has a serious Java fetish. Why not `has_wall_above()` or `has_top()`? Or even `hasTop()` if you insist? I'm not saying this solely to be abusive - function names should be self-explanatory, and yours are not. I had no idea what `getVisit` meant, or `getCellHasTop`. I had to read the code to figure out what should have been immediately obvious.

Comment: Next: when you have a function that is a *predicate* - that is, it exists to answer a question - you should not be comparing it to anything. **It's a predicate!** Predicates are boolean by nature, and so you just use their return value in conditional statements: either `if (getCellHasTop(maze, row, col)) {` or `if (!getCellHasTop(maze, row, col)) {`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon, and more urgently, about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've provided links to the source code; that helps, but it is preferable if we don't have to go offsite.  Your code is very sloppily laid out, and contains an awful lot of comments.  When putting code here, avoid tabs and copy it into the edit box and lay it as you want (no tabs), and then when it looks okay (ignoring the preview — did I mention making sure there are no tabs?) then select it and indent with the **`{}`** button above the edit box.  Now look at the preview.

Comment: did you step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: @pm100 when I did I get a segemation error on the getCellHasLeft and

Comment: @AustinHastings Function names were by professor... Professor mostly teaches java and got forced to teach C I heard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies in code like this:

```
    if(getCellHasTop(maze, row, column + 1) != 1)//Wall check, Zero meaning NO WALL
    {
             //++st;
             //gets that position and sees if it is unvisited... 
             //need a test if it is visited.. if it has been visited before.. Set current spot as BAD_PATH
             if(getVisit(maze,row,column+j) == UNVISITED)
             {
                setVisit(maze, row, column+1, GOOD_PATH);
              successful = step(maze, row, column + 1);
             }
          // if(getVisit(maze, row, column+j) == GOOD_PATH)
          //   {
          //   setVisit(maze, row-i, column, BAD_PATH);
      //   successful = step(maze, row, column+j);
        //      }
             if(successful)
               return 1;  
    }
```

First, you are iterating from -2 to +2. But I think the maze cells are contiguous, so you shouldn't do that. Instead, do something like this:
First, test the row,col to be sure they are valid positions in the maze. Next, test the current cell's bits to see if you are allowed to go up, or whatever directions. Then test to see if the target cell is valid. Then test to see if the target cell is blocked by your path already going through it. Then jump in.

```
enum {
    TOP_BLOCKED    = 0x01,
    RIGHT_BLOCKED  = 0x02,
    BOTTOM_BLOCKED = 0x04,
    LEFT_BLOCKED   = 0x08,
};

#define ABOVE(r,c)     (r),((c)+1)
#define BELOW(r,c)     (r),((c)-1)
#define LEFT_OF(r,c)   ((r)-1),(c)
#define RIGHT_OF(r,c)  ((r)+1),(c)

#define IN_MAZE(m,r,c) ((r)>=0 && (c)>=0 && (r)<(m)->rows && (c)<(m)->cols)
#define CELL(m,r,c) ((m)->maze[(r)][(c)])
#define TOP_OPEN(m,r,c) (in_maze(m, r, c) \
                        && !(CELL(m,r,c) & TOP_BLOCKED) 
                        && in_maze(m,ABOVE(r,c)))
#define VISITED(m,r,c) (getVisit(m,r,c) != UNVISITED)


// ... later, in your step function ...

#define POS  row,column

setVisit(maze, POS, GOOD_PATH);

if (TOP_OPEN(maze, POS) && !VISITED(maze, ABOVE(POS)) && step(maze, ABOVE(POS))) {
    // We found a successful path! Stop looking.
    return 1;
}

if (RIGHT_OPEN(maze, POS) ... && step(maze, RIGHT_OF(POS))) {
    return 1;
}

if (BOTTOM_OPEN ...

if (LEFT_OPEN ...
    return 1;
}

// There is no path from here that solves the maze.
setVisit(maze, POS, UNVISITED);
#undef POS

return 0;
```